# Как через C++ Builder закрыть запущенное скрипт в терминале?

Tags: c++, c++builder, embarcadero

Всем добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста:
У меня есть приложение на C++ Builder и из него я вызываю скрипт на Python через терминал, как правильно закрыть терминальное окно с Python?
Почему спрашиваю - прочитал что через TerminateProcess этого лучше не делать.
Подскажите способ как сделать закрытие терминального окна правильно?

Comment: Оно закроется по окончании процесса, чего и следует дождаться.

Comment: у меня скрипт на python работает в бесконечном цикле - пока его не закроешь